# How to sent file via mail step?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

There is a condition ,which requires to sent multiple mails in gmail and that too very frequently.that is after every 10 minutes a mail will be triggered showing success and failure along with audit table details which consists of job_key,line read,lines write status.etc, etc.But while using mail step it is giving some problems .So we are using python scripts for that.
Is there any way to reswolve this issue by pentaho itself

Comment: please share the script which you have written ...if the python script is creating the issue or the transformation Mail settings ?

Comment: Actually Rishu after Python script calling it is working very fast.But while mail step it is a bit slow.So no issues from python script but with PDI mail step

Comment: try checking the SMTP address and port which is triggering the mails. the issue might be with the slow network connectivity or stuff !!! It would be really useful if you can share screenshot of your PDI Mailer step to understand the issue better !!

Comment: I use the mail step with PDI and GMail all the time.  be sure to enable the ssl option.  What exactly is your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tricky, here's what you need to do within the `Mail` step:

1. Under the `Email Message` tab, make sure the `Use HTML format in mail body?` check box is checked;
2. Switch to the `Attached Files` tab and set up the configurations per your requirements;

I hope this helps.